# Threads.nthreads in Julia Call

Tags: r, multithreading, julia

I'm using the JuliaCall library to use Julia code in R. I'm trying to increase the number of threads but I can't seem to succeed.
I'm using Windows 10 and RStudio version 1.4.1103

Thank you so much!

Comment: What code are you using? What error are you getting? How do you know you're not succeeding. Please **edit your question** to provide more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run

```
Sys.setenv(JULIA_NUM_THREADS = "8")
```

before calling `library(JuliaCall)`.

Here is a full console output on my machine:

```
> Sys.setenv(JULIA_NUM_THREADS = "8")
> library(JuliaCall)
> julia_command("Threads.nthreads()")
Julia version 1.6.0 at location C:\JULIA-~1.0\bin will be used.
Loading setup script for JuliaCall...
Finish loading setup script for JuliaCall.
8
```